# Bootstrap problems with img-responsive and div tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center" style="background-color:#1a242f;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="imageheader col-sm-4">
            <a href="index.php">    
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo & name.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="search col-sm-4" style="padding-left : 12%;">
            <ul class="list-group" style="background-color: #6ABED8;">
                <li>
                    <a href="careersatbvimit.php" style="color: white;">
                        Career's At BVIMIT
                    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="studentlogin.php" style="color: white;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp; Student Login
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    <br><br><br><br>
          <p class="socialicons" style="color : #f4511e; margin-left: 40%;">
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook logo" style="color: #48A6BD"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter logo" style="color: #48A6BD"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube logo" style="color: #48A6BD"></a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. When I use `img-responsive`, the image becomes small when the
   browser increases the "tablet-size". But is perfect for mobile-size and tablet-size browser.
   When I change `img-responsive` to `image-fluid`, the image size
   is what i want for the **desktop-size** browser.
   But the `<p>` elements gets overlapped on it during the resizing of the browser. Also when I resize the browser to "mobile-size"(using `image-fluid`), I get a horizontal scroll-bar for my image since it doesn't resize and stays as it was on **desktop-size** browser. 
   **What has to be removed in my code to make it responsive(with height and width being responsive) on all screens?**
2. My second problem is that, i have to use an empty `div` from left for 2 cols to place my image at the center of the screen **(third line from top)**. Can I place my `div`(using `col-*-*`) in the center without using any empty `div` tags. ? Is there any css code for that ?
3. I used `padding-left : 12%` to make the size of the `<ul>` small and be on the right side of the column. Can it be resized and placed on right without using `padding-left` ?

Comment: Hi Aman, more people will be able to help out here if you can frame the question with a better title, perhaps indicating it's a problem you are having using Bootstrap?

Comment: What's the version of Bootstrap that you are using?

Comment: @horyd yeah it is in bootstrap since my image doesnt resize when using image-fluid, and becomes too small when using img-responsive.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Bootstrap v3.3.7 (as shown in bootstrap.css)

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, i found a quick fix by setting `style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"` on your image (max-width prevent the image to overflow, height auto keeps the proportions).

Your second problem is just a bootstrap class you are missing : col-XX-offset-X, in your example you need to set `<div class=col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2>`

For your third question, you can avoid the padding by setting on your right aligned element a `width` and a `left margin`like so :

`<ul class="list-group" style="background-color: #6ABED8;width:60%;margin:0 0 0 auto">`

Hope that helps

Comment: Solution for third question worked. But rest two are still the same. Image being small in desktop-size browser and the empty div tags.